# MYSQL Routine with fulltext search on temp table. Performance Issues

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, routines

I have a table Called "Item" that is INNODB and has the following layout:

ID
DESCRIPTION ->fulltext index.
DATE

The Fulltext Index is set to index words that are 1 character, unfortunately I can't get around this requirement.  The following Routine runs fine when a user searches larger words such as "item 59929", however some situations will result in a search like "item 1 a 22 4 c" where the spaces have to remain that way.  The database CRAWLS when these 1 character searches are executed.  What is the best way to handle this in the routine? I did hit a road block because it seems that you can not create full text index on temporary tables with the innodb engine, they have to by myisam. Here is a simplified version of what i am currently using:

```
drop temporary table if exists tmpFilter;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpFilter(
ID INT,
Description Varchar(320),
Date datetime,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)) ENGINE=MYISAM; --  HAS TO BE MY ISAM as of 5.6 FULL TEXT ON TEMP INNODB IS NOT ALLOWED

ALTER TABLE tmpFilter ADD FULLTEXT INDEX(description);  -- ADD FULL TEXT
ALTER TABLE tmpFilter DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO tmpFilter
SELECT ID, Description, Date
FROM item
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
    AND description LIKE CONCAT('%item 1 2 a 4%');
    AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('"1 2 a 4" @30' in boolean mode);



ALTER TABLE tmpFilter ENABLE KEYS; 

SELECT * 
FROM tmpFILTER
WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('+item +1 +2 +a +4' in boolean mode);
```

I have tried a few different things but they are making absolutely no difference.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: the new version(s) off MySQl support FULLTEXT indexes on innodb. What are the number of records in the item table?

Comment: correct, i have FULLTEXT indexes on innodb tables, but the issue is that you cannot apply FULLTEXT indexes on a TEMPORARY innodb table in routines.  There are currently 575,000 items.

Comment: Is it possible to make a small sql dump (maybe 40 - 50 records) from the table item that you can insert op sqlfriddle. and paste the link here? FULLTEXT index will never outperform a beter design that will hold the search terms as a many to many relation ship aleast if you index this correcly the real challenge is to simulute the match with boolean mode

Comment: after more hours digging the slowness is all being caused by this line "AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('"1 2 a 4" @30' in boolean mode);"  If i could speed up the proximity search it would be almost instant.

Comment: could you pass in a explain off (a screenshot would be nice) the query and the query what your are running? you are running? Iam wondering if "using temporary table" shows up by extra column then maybe i have a answer that would speed up your query